# FileInputStream & FileOutputStream. Cannot get the information inside the file

Tags: java, java-io

```
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;

    try {
        FileInputStream inFile_Customer = new FileInputStream("database\\Customers.bin");
        ObjectInputStream ois_Customer = new ObjectInputStream(inFile_Customer);
        customerList = (ArrayList<Customer>)ois_Customer.readObject();

        FileInputStream inFile_Package = new FileInputStream("database\\Packages.bin");
        ObjectInputStream ois_Package = new ObjectInputStream(inFile_Package);
        packageList = (ArrayList<Packages>)ois_Package.readObject();

        FileInputStream inFile_Order = new FileInputStream("database\\Orders.bin");
        ObjectInputStream ois_Order = new ObjectInputStream(inFile_Order);
        orderList = (ArrayList<Order>)ois_Order.readObject();

        FileInputStream inFile_Invoice = new FileInputStream("database\\Invoices.bin");
        ObjectInputStream ois_Invoice = new ObjectInputStream(inFile_Invoice);
        invoiceList = (ArrayList<Invoice>)ois_Invoice.readObject();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException |IOException | ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    public void WriteCustomer(){
     try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("database\\Customers.bin");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(customerList);
        oos.close();
     } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    public void WritePackage(){
     try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("database\\Packages.bin");
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         oos.writeObject(packageList);
         oos.close();
     } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     }

     public void WriteOrder(){
       try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("database\\Orders.bin");
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         oos.writeObject(orderList);
         oos.close();
       } catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     }

     public void WriteInvoice(){
       try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("database\\Invoices.bin");
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         oos.writeObject(invoiceList);
         oos.close();
       } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
```

This is my coding. It didn't show any error but it just can't work. The information is written inside file. But it just can't read the file inside. Please help me. I'm new in java. Thanks alot. I can send you my full coding if you requested to check. Thanks.

Comment: Define 'can't work' and 'cant read the file inside'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which should work:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static class Customer implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        

        private String name;

        public Customer() {
        }       

        public Customer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }       

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Customer{" + "name=" + name + '}';
        }                
    }

    private ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void writeCustomers(String path) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos_Customer = null;
        try {
            oos_Customer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
            oos_Customer.writeObject(customerList);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (oos_Customer != null) { // old-style safe closing when done
                try {
                    oos_Customer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void readCustomers(String path) {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois_Customer = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))) { // new-style safe closing when done

            customerList = (ArrayList<Customer>) ois_Customer.readObject();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Test t = new Test();
        t.customerList.add(new Customer("A"));
        t.customerList.add(new Customer("B"));

        System.out.println("Initial customer list: " + t.customerList);

        t.writeCustomers("Customers.bin");

        t.customerList.clear();

        t.readCustomers("Customers.bin");

        System.out.println("Read customer list: " + t.customerList);
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

- Make sure your class implements java.io.Serializable and has set serialVersionUID to any constant long value. This will help you if you change the class and then read a file with the old ones
- Use the wrapper pattern "new SomeStream(new SomeOtherStream(...))". Usually there is no need to have 2 different variables instead one which points to the outer stream. When you close the outer stream, it closes all the streams in the chain.

  - In general, your code looks correct. Just make sure you specify the same path for both input and output files and make sure you check the right instance of ArrayList after it is read :)

If it still doesn't work for you, publish the whole code, please.